# How to delete mail from POP server

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail, pop3

Hi boys and girls(ofcourse)

I want to delete some mails from the pop server by their Message-ID, but it isn't working

What I'm doing wrong?

```
MessageIDTerm[] toDelete = maildb.getMarkAsErased()
//just constructs an array from stored string by me;
if (toDelete.length>0){
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    Message[] mm = inbox.search(new OrTerm(toDelete));
    for (Message m :mm) {
        m.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
        maildb.deleteMail(Utils.getMessageID(m));
    }
    //inbox.delete(true); I should NOT delete de inbox folder :D LOL
    inbox.close(true);
}
```

**EDIT:**

java mail 1.4

android build tools 23.0.3

compiled android sdk 23

Comment: Are you testing on an emulator ?

Comment: nop, I'm using my K10 celPhone

Comment: Can you please tag, what API you are using? Because this isn't stock android, and there isn't really enough code to reliable say if this is using the Java Mail API. If it *is* java mail, you probably want to call [`.expunge()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#expunge()) instead of [`.delete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#delete(boolean)). `.delete()` is for deleting folders, not for deleting messages from folders.

Comment: Already tried with expunge and nothing does not erase.
I am about to believe that it is a problem with my POP server

Comment: Will it have something to do that I open and close the folder to download the mails and then re-open it to delete?

Comment: with the expunge method its says me b:1javax.mail.MethodNotSupportedException: Expunge not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally there is a solution

I'd force to cast to POPMessage and then delete

```
((POPMessage)m).setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
```